# Reading inotify file descriptor fills the buffer with binary garbage

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I was trying my hand at inotify and the following snippet of a code is what I thought would be a good demo of its capabilities:

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>  /* inotify_init(), inotify_add_watch(), IN_* */
#include <stdlib.h>       /* EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE, malloc() */
#include <stdio.h>        /* printf(), puts(), perror() */
#include <unistd.h>       /* read() */
#include <sys/ioctl.h>    /* ioctl, FIONREAD */
#define PTRY(expr)  if((expr) == -1)
#define PGOTO(label, msg) do{\
    perror(msg);\
    goto label;\
  } while(0)


int main(void) {

  int fd;
  PTRY(fd = inotify_init())                       PGOTO(failure, "inotify_init");
  PTRY(inotify_add_watch(fd, ".", IN_ALL_EVENTS)) PGOTO(failure, "inotify_add_watch");

  while(1) {

    unsigned int avail;                           /* We find out how large a buffer we need */
    PTRY(ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &avail))             PGOTO(failure, "ioctl");

    char buffer[avail];
    ssize_t count = read(fd, buffer, avail);      /* We fill the buffer */
    if(avail > 0 && count < avail)                PGOTO(failure, "read");

    printf("Avail: %d, Read: %d\n", (int)avail, (int)count);
    if(avail > 0) puts("");

    for(ssize_t i = 0; i < count; ) {             /* For each event structure in the buffer */

      struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*)buffer + i;
      printf("Byte: %d - %d out of %d\n", (int)i, (int)(sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len), (int)count);

      if(event->len > 0) {                        /* We print its contents */
        printf("Name: %s\n",   event->name);
      } printf("Cookie: %d\n", event->cookie);

      if(event->mask & IN_ACCESS)         puts("IN_ACCESS");
      if(event->mask & IN_ATTRIB)         puts("IN_ATTRIB");
      if(event->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)    puts("IN_CLOSE_WRITE");
      if(event->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE)  puts("IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE");
      if(event->mask & IN_CREATE)         puts("IN_CREATE");
      if(event->mask & IN_DELETE)         puts("IN_DELETE");
      if(event->mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)    puts("IN_DELETE_SELF");
      if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY)         puts("IN_MODIFY");
      if(event->mask & IN_MOVE_SELF)      puts("IN_MOVE_SELF");
      if(event->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)     puts("IN_MOVED_FROM");
      if(event->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)       puts("IN_MOVED_TO");
      if(event->mask & IN_OPEN)           puts("IN_OPEN");
      puts("");

      i += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;

    }

  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;

  failure:
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

}
```

I am, however, receiving some extraneous records from the `read(2)` call, filled with binary rubbish. Enclosed is the output of the program upon the invocation of `cat notifyTest.c` from the shell:

```
Avail: 0, Read: -1
Avail: 64, Read: 64

Byte: 0 - 32 out of 64
Name: notifyTest.c
Cookie: 0
IN_OPEN

Byte: 32 - 32783 out of 64
Name: ▒▒▒
Cookie: 1726459283
IN_ACCESS
IN_ATTRIB
IN_CLOSE_WRITE
IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE
IN_CREATE
IN_DELETE
IN_DELETE_SELF
IN_MODIFY
IN_MOVE_SELF
IN_MOVED_FROM
IN_MOVED_TO
IN_OPEN

Avail: 0, Read: -1
Avail: 32, Read: 32

Byte: 0 - 32 out of 32
Name: notifyTest.c
Cookie: 0
IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE
```

This is potentially code-breaking, since the process would be signaled `SIGSEGV` and killed while reading `event->name` if there weren't any terminating `'\0'` character within the bounds of the statically allocated buffer.

Could this be a quirk, or am I just doing something terribly wrong? My `uname -a` is:

```
Linux witiko-D830 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'll be grateful for any pointers as to what could have gone amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
 struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*)buffer + i;
```

That line is casting the pointer `buffer` to type `struct inotify_event*`, then doing the addition of `i`, which, on your second iteration, is 32. That then increments the values by `32 * sizeof(struct inotify_event)`.

The fix would be:

```
 struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*)(buffer + i);
```